# Row of GridControl Focused on Textbox Value

Tags: vb.net, focus, devexpress, desktop-application, xtragrid

I have a GridControl of DevExpress. I want the Focus on particular row according the `Id` which I entered in the `textbox` above the GridControl.

For example, if I enter 10 in textbox then in the gridCOntrol the row having `Id = 10` got focused.

Comment: Please don't just radically change your question. Let the old one die and ask a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the following code:

```
    int rowHandle = gridView1.LocateByDisplayText(0, gridView1.Columns["Id"], "10");
    if(rowHandle != GridControl.InvalidRowHandle)
        gridView1.FocusedRowHandle = rowHandle;
```